# Can I use Flutter or Android Studio to design front end instead of using react.js and still be able to interact with ethereum?

Tags: go-ethereum, ethereumjs, frontend, mastering-ethereum

I am new to blockchain and currently learning solidity. I have understood the concept behind blockchain and solidity is also good so far. I can design mocha tests and deploy the contract on local ganache-cli. Now I want to design front end to interact with it.
Can I do that with Flutter?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, but there are not many examples out there yet. Check out these two packages:

- ethereum: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/ethereum
- web3dart: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/web3dart

If you are looking for an example project you can check out the Puton moble app project https://github.com/failnicely/puton_mobile_app which is using the EOS blockchain testnet. It is using direct http calls against the dev.cryptolions.io server chain instead of the aforementioned packages.